# Dividing two numbers by subtraction in emu8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

The question reads "Just as it is possible to multiply by adding over and over, it is possible to divide by subtracting over and over. Write a program with a procedure to compute how many times a number N1 goes into another number N2. You will need a loop, and count for how many times that loop is executed". I am really stuck at the subtraction phase. I know I have to create a loop but I don't know where to place it.

```
org 100h

.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA

MSG1 DB 'FIRST > $'
MSG2 DB 'SECOND > $'
MSG3 DB 'THE SUBTRACTION OF '
VALUE1 DB ?
MSG4 DB ' AND '


VALUE2 DB ?, ' IS '

SUM DB ?,'.$'

CR DB 0DH, 0AH, '$'

.CODE
MAIN PROC
;INITIALIZE DS
MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX 
;PROMPT FOR FIRST INPUT
LEA DX, MSG1
MOV AH, 9H
INT 21H
MOV AH, 1H
INT 21H
MOV VALUE1, AL
MOV BH, AL
SUB BH, '0'
;CARRIAGE RETURN FORM FEED
LEA DX, CR
MOV AH, 9H
INT 21H
;PROMPT FOR SECOND INPUT
LEA DX, MSG2
MOV AH, 9H
INT 21H
MOV AH, 1H
INT 21H
MOV VALUE2, AL
MOV BL, AL
SUB BL, '0'
SUBTRACT:
;SUB THE VALUES CONVERT TO CHARACTER AND SAVE
SUB BH, BL
ADD BH, '0'
MOV SUM, BH
;CARRIAGE RETURN FORM FEED
LEA DX, CR
MOV AH, 9H
INT 21H
;OUTPUT THE RESULT
LEA DX, MSG3
MOV AH, 9H
INT 21H


TERMINATE:
;RETURN TO DOS
MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: _"but I don't know where to place it"_ You place it at the point where you want to repeat one or more instruction(s) until some condition is met.

Comment: `SUB BH, BL` `ADD BH, '0'` `MOV SUM, BH` Why would you store the result of a __subtraction__ in a variable aptly named to store the result of an __addition__?

Comment: Even if you don't know _where_ to place it, perhaps you know _how_ to write this/any loop. It would encourage us to provide an answer if you showed us this effort.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm for positive N1,N2:

1. prepare `N1`, `N2` and set some `R` to -1
2. increment `R`
3. subtract `N1` from `N2` (update `N2` with result)
4. when result of subtraction is above or equal to zero, go to step 2.
5. `R` has result of integer division `N2`/`N1`

Steps 2. to 4. can be written in x86 Assembly by single instruction per step (the `sub` updates "carry flag", which can be used to decide whether the subtraction did "overflow" - used by one of the "Jcc" = jump-condition-code instructions to either jump somewhere else or continue by next instruction).

Answer (score 0):

Next program does the job. The numbers are declared as variables in the data segment, comments explain everything (just copy-paste it in EMU8086 and run it) :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

n1    dw 3
n2    dw 95
count dw ?
msg   db 'Quotient = $'
str   db 10 dup('$')

.code
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax

;DIVIDE BY SUBTRACTIONS.             
  mov count, 0    ;COUNTER FOR SUBTRACTIONS.
subtract:
;CHECK IF SUBTRACTION CAN BE DONE.
  mov ax, n1      ;COPY N1 INTO AX BECAUSE CAN...
  cmp n2, ax      ;...NOT COMPARE MEMORY-MEMORY.
  jl  finale      ;N2 < N1. NO MORE SUBTRACTIONS.
;SUBTRACT.
  sub n2, ax      ;N2-N1.
  inc count       ;INCREASE SUBTRACTIONS COUNTER.
  jmp subtract    ;REPEAT.  

finale:
;DISPLAY MESSAGE.
  mov ah, 9
  mov dx, offset msg
  int 21h
;CONVERT QUOTIENT (COUNT) INTO STRING.
  mov ax, count
  mov si, offset str
  call number2string
;DISPLAY COUNT (QUOTIENT).
  mov ah, 9
  mov dx, offset str
  int 21h

;WAIT FOR A KEY TO BE PRESSED.         
  mov ah, 0
  int 16h

;EXIT.  
  mov ax, 4c00h
  int 21h

;------------------------------------------
;CONVERT A NUMBER IN STRING.
;ALGORITHM : EXTRACT DIGITS ONE BY ONE, STORE
;THEM IN STACK, THEN EXTRACT THEM IN REVERSE
;ORDER TO CONSTRUCT STRING (STR).
;PARAMETERS : AX = NUMBER TO CONVERT.
;             SI = POINTING WHERE TO STORE STRING.

number2string proc 
  mov  bx, 10 ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
  mov  cx, 0 ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.
cycle1:       
  mov  dx, 0 ;NECESSARY TO DIVIDE BY BX.
  div  bx ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
  push dx ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
  inc  cx ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED.
  cmp  ax, 0  ;IF NUMBER IS
  jne  cycle1 ;NOT ZERO, LOOP. 
;NOW RETRIEVE PUSHED DIGITS.
cycle2:  
  pop  dx        
  add  dl, 48 ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
  mov  [ si ], dl
  inc  si
  loop cycle2  

  ret
number2string endp
```

Procedure "number2string" is used to convert the result into string, necessary in case this result has more than one digit.

Notice both numbers, dividend (N2) and divisor (N1), are not captured from keyboard, they are static values in the data segment. In order to capture them from keyboard we would need another procedure, "string2number", to convert the strings into numeric format.